# Saving spoiling mushrooms?

Tags: mushrooms, spoilage

Are there any recipes specially for mushrooms that are on their way out, like making banana bread from over-ripe bananas?

Comment: How are your mushrooms spoiling? If I store mine well-aired, they do not spoil but just dry out. If I store them packaged, they do change texture to become somewhat slimy, but by that time, they are already moldy so I toss them out.

Comment: I rent, and with my apartment came a pretty humid refrigerator. Living in Norway I typically get mushrooms in a perforated plastic container, which I leave them in until I've used them. Perhaps just an open bowl or something would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "on their way out". If they are just starting to develop a slimy sheen, cook them as soon as possible - much more than that and you'll want to throw them away.

In this state they should be OK to slice into sauces like bolognese.

You could cut them into a very fine dice and gently fry in butter. The resulting delicious black mush is a good omelette filling, or you can refrigerate/freeze it to use later as an umami additive for sauces.

Answer (score 4):

I like to make stock with them. Here's one recipe I use:

http://markbittman.com/very-flavorful-vegetable-stock-in-1-hour/

I think Bittman also has a specifically mushroom stock recipe in *How To Cook Everything Vegetarian*...

Comment: Making stock is a great way to use up lots of things that are on their way out.